# remember me checkbox in login that using token in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, react-hooks, session-cookies

I want to add a Clickable “Remember Me” checkbox in my login page that tells the browser to save a cookie so that if you close out the window for the site without signing out, the next time you go back, you will be signed back in automatically.that can save username and password

```
export const getUser = () => {
  const userStr = sessionStorage.getItem("user");
  if (userStr) return JSON.parse(userStr);
  else return null;
};

export const getToken = () => {
  return sessionStorage.getItem("token") || null;
};

export const setUserSession = (token, user) => {
  sessionStorage.setItem("token", token);
  sessionStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(user));
};

export const removeUserSession = () => {
  sessionStorage.removeItem("token");
  sessionStorage.removeItem("user");
};
export const handleSuccessfulLogin = async (token, rememberMe) => {
  localStorage.setItem("token", token);
  localStorage.setItem("rememberme", rememberMe);
};
export const handleLogout = () => {
  localStorage.clear();
};
```

This is my login that work with api

```
  const handelLogin = () => {
    setError(null);
    setLoading(true);
    axios
      .post("https://www.mecallapi.com/api/login", {
        username: username,
        password: password,
      })
      .then((response) => {
        setLoading(false);
        setUserSession(response.data.token, response.data.user);
        navigate("/Dashboard");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setLoading(false);
        if (error.response.status === 401 || error.response.status === 400) {
          setError(error.response.data.message);
        } else {
          setError("somthing went wrong ,please try again");
        }
      });
  };
```

This is my remember me checkbox

```
<div className="login-bottom">
  <Checkbox {...label} />
</div>
```

Comment: Seems like a simple if statement to check `if getuser != null { load specific compoenent }` else render login screen